# dalvik vm heap compaction

Tags: android, dalvik

In dalvik, how can it handle memory fragmentation?
I know it has a garage collector. But what if my application allocates a lot of 'small' object and then free some of them and free memory is scattered around. How can the dalvik find memory when my application tries to allocate a large memory (there is enough free memory available for this allocation but the free memory is scattered around)?

Comment: AFAIK, Dalvik still does not have a compacting garbage collector, but I have not heard anything one way or another in quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector create collection tree. Collection tree contains object reference if object reference null garbage collector remove this object from tree.